# How to mount unused space to my ubuntu partition?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, gparted, disk-usage

I am having issues mounting some space on my harddrive to Ubuntu. I have about 800gb of unused space, that I never used when installing Ubuntu.

I wish to use that now, but I am not sure where to begin.

Ubuntu is in `/dev/sdb3` and the unused space is in `/dev/sdb1`, both file systems are ext4, but when I press resize/move on my disk, it wont let me.

Here is a picture of my partitions in case it helps:

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome. To be able to expand the sb3 would need to be beside sb1, It looks like sb2 is in the way. This can be done but the chance of losing date is quite high. You need to do a full back up first. I suggest you read this tutorial first. https://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dmoving-space-between-partitions

Comment: Thank you @David, is there anything i can do to lower the risk of loosing data? i made a backup just in case, but if possible i'd like to lower the chances of any issues happening.

Comment: No not really, since you need to shift 1 partition out of the way of the other it can be dangerous..

Comment: There is never a danger of loosing data if you have a good backup of your user data. If you don't, then you do not care about your user data, so loosing data in that case is not an issue. In this case here I would reinstall if I wished a different partitioning. Else, you can mount the current sdb1 and use it for data storage (archive, movies, pictures, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 95 GiB system partition, `sdb3`, is at the end, after a small EFI partition, `sdb2`. First on your drive is the very large 836 GiB, ext4 formatted `/dev/sdb1` partition. There is no "best way" to partition. In the end, it depends on the preference of the user. I see following options:

**Leave the partitions as they are**

This partitioning is not straighforward, but still is perfectly fine and useable as is.

- 95 GiB is quite large, certainly much more than needed by the Ubuntu system files. An Ubuntu system needs 15 tot 20 Gib, thus you can perfectly use that partition also for storing quite some user data. This is how your system currently is configured. You therefore could keep things as is, and use that partition to store all files that are in active use.
- The 836 GiB could then be used as a larger data storage area, for storing archived data, photo's, movies, music, .... It could also be used for audio or video editing, tasks that require large amounts of data.

**Reinstall**

A reinstall would be by far the easiest to get to a more "straightforward" partitioning. You then let the installer erase and use the whole disk. You will end up with an EFI partition at the start, and then one single partition on the entire disk. This is the most simple, but also the default, setup.

**Repartition**

The same could be achieved if you repartition manually. That, however, would be a lengthy process because it would require moving partitions, making the system bootable again, etc. Not recommended, unless you have very good technical knowledge about linux.

*Remark*

Whatever you do, make sure you have a good backup of your personal user data anytime. In any of the scenario's, but also during daily computer use, something can go wrong, causing you to loose your personal data. An operating system is downloaded for free and installed in less than an hour. Your personal data, once lost, can never be replaced.

Comment: Thank you, i think i'll just use the e xtra partition as extra storage, would i need to mount this or is it already mounted?

Comment: Normally not, you need to click it first in Files to mount it. If it is archive data, that may be fine. Else you can use "Disks" to configure that drive to automount through /etc/fstab (or edit /etc/fstab yourself)..